# How to get to storage/emulated/0

Tags: android

I want to access storage/emulated/0 via finder in Mac OSX and save a file in it for reading on a program that I created. Is there a way to access, connect, or mount files through Mac OSX? Any other suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use device file explorer and paste on desired destination. In your case 
**storage->emulated->0**

[image]

Comment: Thanks... Although, it's not clear on how to paste item on device explorer.

Comment: @skippyHippy Just Right click on the \0 folder and you will find Add/Push File.

Comment: For me, it says: "Access denied".

Comment: @waldgeist you can only access the folder if the app is running in debug mode, I mean if you want to expand apps downloaded from playstore/installer as release version you can't.

Comment: @JawadZeb Thanks, that's good to know. Maybe I hadn't activated debug mode when trying to access the data.